# Is it possible to restrict the values of optional parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, default-value, optional-parameters

C# allows the use of [*optional parameters*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx): one can specify the value in case the parameter is omitted in a call and the compiler then specifies the value itself.

Example:

```
public interface IFoo {

    void SomeMethod (int para = 0);

}
```

This idea is useful but a problem is that one can define several "default values" on different levels of the class hierarchy. Example:

```
public class SubFoo : IFoo {

    public void SomeMethod (int para = 1) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

If one later calls:

```
SubFoo sf = new SubFoo ();
sf.SomeMethod ();
Foo f = sf;
f.SomeMethod ();
```

The result is that the first call is done with `para` equal to `1` and the second with `para` equal to `0` (as interface). This make sense since the compiler adds the default values and in the first case the `this` is a `SubFoo` thus the default value is `1`.

It is of course up to the programmer to maintain consistency, but such schizophrenic situations can easily occur when a programmer changes his/her mind in the middle of the process and forgets to modify all default values.

Problematic is that the compiler doesn't warn that different default values are in use whereas this can be checked by moving up the class hierarchy. Furthmore some people might mimic default parameters with:

```
public class SubFoo2 {

    public virtual void SomeMethod () {
        SomeMethod(1);
    }

    public void SomeMethod (int para) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Which allows dynamic binding and thus overriding consistently. It thus requires one to be very careful with how default values are "implemented".

Are there ways to enforce (with compiler flags for instance) to check whether the default values are consistent? If not it would be nice to have at least a warning that something is not really consistent.

Comment: No, but you could write a Roslyn diagnostic.

Comment: "and forgets to modify all default values" --- when such case happens it's a sign that the application design is broken (or is starting to break).

Comment: @zerkms: true, but as they say in *software architecture*: *"software architecture is the aim to make foolproof systems, the aim of the universe is creating more fools, currently the universe is winning."*.

Comment: OK .. I can do that if at first you define `consistent`

Comment: @PeterM: The same as the matching interface or base class method.

Comment: @PeterM: consistent means that all methods definitions that share the same methods use the same default value. So of you have `SubFoo1` and `SubFoo2`, they should share the same default value.

Comment: @SLaks  But how does the compiler determine programmer intent?

Comment: If your input parameter can accept the full rnage of `int` then why is `1` wrong as a  default value than `0`. I assume `SubFoo` implements `Foo` and for `SubFoo` it may make sense to redefine the default value. Otherwise you should use enums instead of `int` to restrict the range.

Comment: @PeterM: What do you mean with programmer intent? From the moment you use two default values for the same "base method", you know you're looking for trouble, regardless of the real context.

Comment: @xxbbcc: It can make sense, but in most cases, this makes things way more complicated.

Comment: @CommuSoft  How does the compiler differentiate between the programmer deliberately doing something and and just screwing up, if both end results are considered valid by the language?

Comment: "you know you're looking for trouble, regardless of the real context" --- that's not that obvious. Those are local method-scoped variables. Not sure how they may affect anything (or each other).

Comment: You mean `public class SubFoo : IFoo { .. }`

Comment: @ja72: yes, modified, thanks.

Comment: @CommuSoft The compiler simply translates the default parameter to its actual value and puts it on the stack before the call. How is this different from a developer making a direct call to the same method with `1` as the input parameter? This is why I asked about the range of acceptable values.

Comment: Actrually it seems silly to me to include a default parameter declaration in a interface. Default parameters should be part of the implementation and not the interface.

Comment: @xxbbcc: the point is that if you mimic default behavior as demonstrated above, you allow the default value to be consistent: if you redefine the default value for a `SubFoo2`, it will always give `1`, regardless from where it is called whereas defining it as with `=`, it depends only from where you call it. That is quite against oo-programming.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, I agree with you that it's against OO programming. I think ja72's comment is right and having a default value in the interface is problematic (although this doesn't solve your problem).

Comment: @ja72: true, but it is also possible to define `SubFoo` that uses default value `1` and `SubSubFoo` that uses default value `2`. The purpose of defining it on the interface level was to shorten the question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not necessary compile-time solution - but you can make unit test for that (I suspect that you're taking seriously unit testing and you run them frequently if you ask this kind of question). The idea is to create assertion method like `AssertThatDefaultParametersAreEqual(Type forType)` - find all classes that are not `abstract` (using reflection) and inherit from `forType` then iterate over all methods which have defined default parameters:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfo = Type.GetType(classType).GetMethods(BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding | BindingFlags.Invoke);
```

Group them by `MethodInfo.Name` and check does within the group all same parameters with default values (could be obtained by `MethodInfo.GetParameters().Where(x => x.IsOptional)`) have the equal property of `ParameterInfo.DefaultValue`.

edit: btw. that might not work in Mono because compilers aren't obligated to emit for instance: `Optional` BindingFlag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a compile time indication that a method is changing the default value of an optional argument, you're going to need to use some sort of 3rd party code analysis tool, as C# itself doesn't provide any means of providing such a restriction, or any warnings when its done.

---

As a workaround, one option is to avoid using optional parameter values and instead use multiple overloads.  Since you have an interface here, that would mean using an extension method so that the implementation of the overload with a default value is still defined in the general case:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void SomeMethod(int para);
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void SomeMethod(this IFoo foo)
    {
        foo.SomeMethod(0);
    }
}
```

So while this approach does *technically* still allow someone to create an extension (or instance) method named `SomeMethod` and accepting no `int` argument, it would mean that someone would really need to go out of their way to actively change the "default value".  It doesn't *require* implementations of the interface to supply the default value, which risks them unintentionally providing the wrong default value.

Comment: If you are locking `foo.SomeMethod()` to that extent, why do you even need a default/any parameter?

Comment: @PeterM I don't understand your question.  This *is* functionally providing a default value, it's just not using the C# function for default parameters to achieve that goal.  The end result is still that someone using the interface doesn't need to provide the `int` value, and that `0` is used as the default.  It also ensures that those implementing the method would have to actively go out of their way to change the default value, even though it can't entirely prevent it.

Comment: I maybe half asleep right now, but if code depends on the value consistency of a parameter then I am thinking that the parameter is an over-specification.

Answer (score 0):

Define `const int DefaultPara = 1;` and then use that instead of hard coding numerical values.

```
interface IFoo 
{
    void SomeMethod (int para = DefaultPara);
}

public class SubFoo : IFoo {

    public void SomeMethod (int para = DefaultPara) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: What if someone still uses hardcoded `int para = 1`?